# Manually submit a Dojo Dialog

Tags: dojo, dialog

I've created a dialog in dojo with a few input fields.  Based upon a few criteria, I'd like to dynamically the destination url the data is posted to within that dialog (the equivalent of the action attribute on a form).  Yet I see no way to set a dialog's action, or even how to manually submit it.

Here is a bare-bones version of the dialog:

```
<div id="my_dialog" dojoType="dojo.dijit.Dialog" style="display:none;" title="My Dialog">
<input type="text" dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="input_1" name="input_1" value="info" />
<button type="submit" dojoType="dijit.form.Button">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out and will share what I learned.

If you put a form inside of the dialog, you can access it just like any other Dojo form.  But you have to make sure that dialog is not already in another form.  That was my problem, it caused the inner form to disappear when the dialog is moved to the end of the body tag.

```
<div id="my_dialog" dojoType="dojo.dijit.Dialog" style="display:none;" title="My Dialog">
<form id="my_form" dojotType="dijit.form.Form" method="post" action="/path/">
<input type="text" dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="input_1" name="input_1" value="info" />
<button type="submit" dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onclick="return someFunction();">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Using the structure above, you have a couple of options to get the form's values: from the dialog, or from the form.  That means dijit.byId("my_dialog").attr("value") is the same as dijit.byId("my_form").attr("value").  That was what originally confused me and made me thing the dialog itself could act as a form.

To process or validate the form before it is submitted, add onclick="return someFunction();", and make sure that function returns true only if the form should be submitted.

One additional pitfall is that all inputs in the dialog are moved to the end of the dom.  So if you did not have the form inside the dialog, and you expected those inputs in the dialog to be submitted with a parent form, that isn't going to happen.  In this case, I create hidden fields inside the parent form, then manually copy the dialog input values into them before submitting.

Answer (score 0):

`dijit.Dialog` doesn't have the capability to submit itself manually. It's just a container and you should manage the content in it yourself.

If you want to submit the dialog, just attach some events to the submit button and use XHR to submit the data. When the submission is completed, close the dialog yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I too looked into xhr to manually submit the form data, but I needed to post the data without ajax as the posted data determined where the user would end up next.  That could be done via the xhr callback, but in this case it made sense to perform a normal post.